# Unable to set excel VBA worksheet variable

Tags: excel, vba, ex

I am trying to set a source worksheet variable to a target worksheet variable in another workbook(DataSource1.xlsx) with the purpose of eventually using it to read the target worksheet and perform some calculation but it gives me the subscript out of range error.

This is my code

```
Sub GenerateReport()

Dim source As Worksheet

Dim path As String    
Set source= Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.path & "\DataSource1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")

'path = ThisWorkbook.path

'Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.path & "\DataSource1.xlsx")

Dim one As Integer

one = 10

End Sub
```

The file are all placed in the same folder and I have checked that there are no naming or path errors, why is this happening?

**EDIT**

This is what my project looks like after GSerg comments

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the workbook is already opened, you need to refer to it by name without path:

```
Set source = Workbooks("DataSource1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
```

If the workbook is not opened yet, you need to open it first:

```
Set source = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.path & "\DataSource1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Comment: @Computernerd In which way?

Comment: I am getting the same error, subscript out of range error

Comment: @Computernerd You cannot be getting this error on a call to `Workbooks.Open`. That means you are either trying to refer to a workbook that is not opened yet, or that the workbook is opened but it does not have a `Sheet1`.

Comment: oh so I must open the workbook before I can reference it?

Comment: @Computernerd That is what I meant by `If the workbook is not opened yet, you need to open it first` right above.